# Select results from previous select clause, returning a result from a different record

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

Below is the basis I'm using to try to get revision values to line up.  I didn't build the tables, so bear with me as there's obviously some improvements that can be made to the structure

I've tried to simplify the query to make it easier to read, there may be a typo or syntax issue.

---

> **Table1**
>
> KEY1, TagName, ParentTag
>
> 1, TAG1, 1
>
> 2, TAG2, NULL
>
> **Table2**
>
> KEY2, Revision
>
> 1, A

---

Without the middle 'CASE', I get:

KEY1, TagName, Revision

1, Tag1, A

2, Tag2, NULL

I want:

KEY1, TagName, Revision

1, Tag1, A

2, Tag2, A

```
SELECT
KEY1, --Table1
TagName, --Table1

    Case When Revision is null THEN (
        SELECT Revision 
        from TABLE2
        Left  join TABLE1
        ON KEY1 = KEY2
        where TagName like ParentTag)

    ELSE ParentTag
    END as 'REV'

FROM  TABLE1
left join Table2
ON KEY2 = KEY1
```

I've tried a variety of things, this one I can't quite seem to get!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: in the hierarchy, when there are multiple revisions, which one should be selected?

Comment: So for the Revision - you want it if it exists for the Key1 else to try and get from the Key1 of parent tag? If so, how many levels do you go above in parent tag? Ex. if revision exists for first parent, get that? or get the revision only from the ultimate parent? Either way - you'll likely end up with a recursive CTE...

Comment: The idea is that all main items will have a revision. The child items have a single parent (only ever 1 level).  These items are essentially grouped to the parent.  I have the reference to the parent, but trying to query the table to return the parent record and then it's 'revision' to use for the child is the issue

Comment: So if I don't have the second select, I get a NULL for the revision of the child (item 2).  That's why I'm trying to do basically this: IF Revision is null THEN 'use revision of parent item'.  If that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use a `CTS` which, in this case, acts only as a view to create the link between the main table (`Table1`) and the revision table (`Table2`).

It could be written without the use of a `CTS` but it would be far less readable.

```
;With cts_Revision as (
  Select key1, TagName, ParentTag, Revision From Table1 as a
  left join Table2 as b on a.key1 = b.key2

  )

select a.Key1, a.TagName, coalesce(a.revision, parent.revision) as rev
FROM cts_revision as a
left join cts_revision as parent
  on parent.key1 = a.ParentTag
```

Working example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67019/1